# Short array syntax must be used to define arrays Use ::class notation instead

Tags: magento2, array, code

I had things like that

```
  90 | WARNING | [ ] Use ::class notation instead.
  92 | WARNING | [x] Short array syntax must be used to define arrays
  94 | WARNING | [ ] Use ::class notation instead.
  96 | WARNING | [x] Short array syntax must be used to define arrays
  98 | WARNING | [ ] Use ::class notation instead.
 100 | WARNING | [x] Short array syntax must be used to define arrays
 102 | WARNING | [ ] Use ::class notation instead.
```

```
'value' => array(
    array(
        'label' => __('Is New (by a period)'),
        'value' => 'Amasty\Xlanding\Model\Rule\Condition\IsNewByPeriod',
    ),
    array(
        'label' => __('Is New (by \'is_new\' attribute)'),
        'value' => 'Amasty\Xlanding\Model\Rule\Condition\IsNew',
    ),
    array(
        'label' => __('Created (in days)'),
        'value' => 'Amasty\Xlanding\Model\Rule\Condition\Created',
    ),
    array(
        'label' => __('In Stock'),
        'value' => 'Amasty\Xlanding\Model\Rule\Condition\InStock',
    )
);
```

and modified them like that

```
[
    'label' => __('Is New (by a period)'),
    'value' => 'Amasty\Xlanding\Model\Rule\Condition\IsNewByPeriod',
],
[
    'label' => __('Is New (by \'is_new\' attribute)'),
    'value' => 'Amasty\Xlanding\Model\Rule\Condition\IsNew',
],
[
    'label' => __('Created (in days)'),
    'value' => 'Amasty\Xlanding\Model\Rule\Condition\Created',
],
```

but still have those warnings and can't pass pipeline

```
  88 | WARNING | [ ] Use ::class notation instead.
  92 | WARNING | [ ] Use ::class notation instead.
  96 | WARNING | [ ] Use ::class notation instead.
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy, my friend!

```
[
    'label' => __('Is New (by a period)'),
    'value' => \Amasty\Xlanding\Model\Rule\Condition\IsNewByPeriod::class,
],
[
    'label' => __('Is New (by \'is_new\' attribute)'),
    'value' => \Amasty\Xlanding\Model\Rule\Condition\IsNew::class,
],
[
    'label' => __('Created (in days)'),
    'value' => \Amasty\Xlanding\Model\Rule\Condition\Created::class,
]
```

Comment: oh god, Yes it was very easy and I forgot it IDK why.
Thank you so much for so quick reply